# The crop command of ImageJ does not give correct dimension

Tags: imagej

I have an image that is 2048*2048. When I run the following macros:

```
makeRectangle(304, 304, 1450, 1450);
run("Crop");
```

it then results in an image of 1450*1450. Why not (1450-303)*(1450-303)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`makeRectangle`](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#makeRectangle) expects the x and y coordinates of the upper left corner, as well as the **width** and **height** (not the coordinates of the lower right corner) of the rectangular selection.

The line

```
makeRectangle(304, 304, 1450, 1450);
```

is equivalent to

```
run("Specify...", "width=1450 height=1450 x=304 y=304");
```

(see also the [ImageJ user guide](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-27.html#sub%3aSpecify...))